# If Two Filenames in Two Separate Directories Match, Then

Tags: vba, excel, filenames, matching

I have a set of files within two different directories that are similar in the fact that for every file in directory A there is a file in directory B that shares the same first four characters in the prefix (the subject ID). For instance,

Directory A contains files:
001FileNameX,
002FileNameX,
003FileNameX,
etc.

and Directory B contains files:
001FileNameY,
002FileNameY,
003FileNameY,
etc.

What I am trying to create is a macro loop that:

1. Searches both directories until it finds a set of file names that share the same first four characters (e.g. match 001FileNameX in Directory A with 001FileNameY in Directory B)
2. If it finds a matching set, I want it to execute a piece of code. In this case, I want it to copy and paste a range of cells from the file (workbook) in Directory A to the file (different workbook)in Directory B and then close the workbooks (saving the changes to the workbook in Directory B).
3. Then return to the directories and find the next set of matching file names and so on until there are no matches remaining.

I am generally able to use wildcards to search similar files, but this case is different due to the increased specificity- I need the filenames from TWO different directories to MATCH using the first four characters in the prefixes and then loop while allowing the next prefix of four characters to be different from the last prefix. Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about solving this issue?

Below is an example of a code I generally use when the prefixes do not matter or do not change and the workbook I am copy/pasting from is also static. Thanks so much for any help!

---

Sub Insert_Template_With_Formulas()

```
Dim FNames As String
Dim DirectoryA As String    

DirectoryA = Cells(2, 2).Value

ChDrive DirectoryA
ChDir DirectoryA

' Open any file containing "Resps.xlsx", regardless of prefix

 FNames = Dir("*Resps.xlsx")
    If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files in the Directory"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Do While FNames <> ""


        Workbooks.Open ("Resps_Template.xlsx")
            Range("AL1:BX32").Select
            Selection.Copy


        Workbooks.Open (FNames)
            Range("AL1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste


    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close


    Workbooks("Resps_Template.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False


    ChDrive DirectoryA
    ChDir DirectoryA

    ' Call Dir again without arguments to return the next file in the same 
      directory

     FNames = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: All your goals can be done with existing posts in SO. Please research around, then come back with the code you stuck/need help with.

Comment: Do you mean the file name matches exactly or the prefix number matches exactly? And where is your code so far?

Comment: @PatricK I've looked around quite a bit for an answer to this problem (several hours on several occasions), but I can't seem to find any posts that look at how to write a macro that will match a prefix occurring in two separate excel filenames in two different directories when that prefix will change on the next match. Was there a specific post you found relevant that maybe I missed somehow?

Comment: @QHarr I'm sorry, I guess that wasn't as clear as I had hoped. The prefix will match each time while the remainder of the filename will vary between the directories (so I'm not opening two workbooks with the EXACT same name, I know that isn't allowed). I added some extra information in the original post with a code I use to paste a template to many different files meeting a certain criteria when the template does not change and the prefixes are irrelevant.

Comment: 3 number id or 4 number id? Is there a pattern for the id?

Comment: @QHarr They are 3 number IDs followed by a letter. For example, in directory A, [001P_DirectoryA.xlsx // 002P_DirectoryA.xlsx // 003P_DirectoryA.xlsx] and, in directory B, [001P_DirectoryB.xlsx // 002P_DirectoryB.xlsx // 003P_DirectoryB.xlsx]. The IDs normally increase by one each time, but every once in awhile there will be a missing ID number (e.g. 005 will be missing).

Comment: And is there always "_" after those 4 chararacters? And is this pattern unique to the files you care about in the target folder?

Answer (score 0):

Get in array list of all filenames only (w/o path) in Directory A by loop:
`Dir("FullPAth\Directory A\", vbNormal)` with the following `Dir` w/o parameters.
Then iterate this array and check for non-zero results of similar command as:
`Dir("FullPAth\Directory B\" & sArr(i), vbNormal)`.
.